# Why do I get a blank screen when I try to embed a processing sketch on a webpage?

Tags: html, processing, embed

I have a processing sketch (java mode) that I want to embed on an html page. I used this tutorial: [https://cs.nyu.edu/~kapp/cs101/processing_on_the_web/.\](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Ekapp/cs101/processing_on_the_web/.%5C)
Here is what I put in the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Program</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas data-processing-sources="myProgram.pde" width="900" height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I put in myProgram.pde, which is in the same folder as the html file:

```
void setup(){
  size(900, 500);
}
void draw(){
  background(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I have processing.js in the same folder. When I open this in chrome, it's blank. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Processing-JS](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js) has been discontinued for a while, the framework you are looking for is [p5.js](https://p5js.org/), which is basically the "official JavaScript version of Processing".